# Rearrangement of Array of objects into new array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Relatively  new still with Node.js, creating a small project, and looking for a solution to the below. 
In short I am looking to get the total number of "**timeTrack_playTimeTotal**" *(timeTrack_dateOfStart - timeTrack_dateOfEnd)* in minutes for each **timeTrack_profile_uniqueID**.

There is multiple entries for each profile_uniqueID, so need to loop through sample data. 
Below is the output that would be preferred.

**OUTPUT**:

```
[
  { track_profileID: '306', track_totalTime: 43},
  { track_profileID: '71', track_totalTime: 35},
  { track_profileID: '305', track_totalTime: 14},
  { track_profileID: '304', track_totalTime: 5},
]
```

Below code gets me the unique entries into a new array, however I need some assistance in getting the other information to sum up in total against each of the unique ID's. From here I need to perform additional actions based on the total value.

```
TimeTracking.find({}, function(err, allTimeTracks) {

            var newArr = allTimeTracks.map(function(elem) {
                return {
                    track_profileID: elem.timeTrack_profile_uniqueID,
                };
            });

    // Filter array to only have unique profileID's.
    const objArrayUnique = [...new Map(newArr.map(item => [JSON.stringify(item), item])).values()];
    console.log('newArr', objArrayUnique);

    });
```

// Output from above code

```
newArr [   { track_profileID: '306'},   {
track_profileID: '71' },   {
track_profileID: '305'},   {
track_profileID: '304'},   {
track_profileID: '71'} ]
```

**MONGO SAMPLE DATA:**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("62bbeb23175d673b68c2bf27"), "timeTrack_dateOfStart" : ISODate("2022-06-29T06:03:15.683Z"), "timeTrack_uniqueID" : "1656482595683", "timeTrack_profile_uniqueID" : "306", "timeTrack_status" : "closed", "timeTrack_cameraName" : "M0003", "timeTrackCreationDate" : ISODate("2022-06-29T06:03:15.684Z"), "__v" : 0, "timeTrack_dateOfEnd" : ISODate("2022-06-29T06:05:11.118Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("62bbebc7175d673b68c2bf29"), "timeTrack_dateOfStart" : ISODate("2022-06-29T06:05:59.640Z"), "timeTrack_uniqueID" : "1656482759640", "timeTrack_profile_uniqueID" : "306", "timeTrack_status" : "closed", "timeTrack_cameraName" : "M0003", "timeTrackCreationDate" : ISODate("2022-06-29T06:05:59.640Z"), "__v" : 0, "timeTrack_dateOfEnd" : ISODate("2022-06-29T06:08:06.230Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("62bbf265859b02800cf2edfe"), "timeTrack_dateOfStart" : ISODate("2022-06-29T06:34:13.424Z"), "timeTrack_uniqueID" : "1656484453424", "timeTrack_profile_uniqueID" : "71", "timeTrack_status" : "closed", "timeTrack_cameraName" : "M0002", "timeTrackCreationDate" : ISODate("2022-06-29T06:34:13.425Z"), "__v" : 0, "timeTrack_dateOfEnd" : ISODate("2022-06-29T06:52:24.396Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("62bbf265859b02800cf2ee01"), "timeTrack_dateOfStart" : ISODate("2022-06-29T06:34:13.482Z"), "timeTrack_uniqueID" : "1656484453482", "timeTrack_profile_uniqueID" : "305", "timeTrack_status" : "closed", "timeTrack_cameraName" : "M0002", "timeTrackCreationDate" : ISODate("2022-06-29T06:34:13.483Z"), "__v" : 0, "timeTrack_dateOfEnd" : ISODate("2022-06-29T06:49:04.146Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("62bbf26d859b02800cf2ee03"), "timeTrack_dateOfStart" : ISODate("2022-06-29T06:34:21.798Z"), "timeTrack_uniqueID" : "1656484461798", "timeTrack_profile_uniqueID" : "306", "timeTrack_status" : "closed", "timeTrack_cameraName" : "M0003", "timeTrackCreationDate" : ISODate("2022-06-29T06:34:21.799Z"), "__v" : 0, "timeTrack_dateOfEnd" : ISODate("2022-06-29T06:42:34.340Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("62bbf6197768b884d4e33a82"), "timeTrack_dateOfStart" : ISODate("2022-06-29T06:50:01.907Z"), "timeTrack_uniqueID" : "1656485401907", "timeTrack_profile_uniqueID" : "306", "timeTrack_status" : "closed", "timeTrack_cameraName" : "M0003", "timeTrackCreationDate" : ISODate("2022-06-29T06:50:01.910Z"), "__v" : 0, "timeTrack_dateOfEnd" : ISODate("2022-06-29T06:59:49.865Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("62bbf6f07768b884d4e33a83"), "timeTrack_dateOfStart" : ISODate("2022-06-29T06:53:36.978Z"), "timeTrack_uniqueID" : "1656485616978", "timeTrack_profile_uniqueID" : "71", "timeTrack_status" : "closed", "timeTrack_cameraName" : "M0001", "timeTrackCreationDate" : ISODate("2022-06-29T06:53:36.979Z"), "__v" : 0, "timeTrack_dateOfEnd" : ISODate("2022-06-29T07:07:23.639Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("62bcc4d7453bcf3850df4eb5"), "timeTrack_dateOfStart" : ISODate("2022-06-29T21:32:07.868Z"), "timeTrack_uniqueID" : "1656538327868", "timeTrack_profile_uniqueID" : "304", "timeTrack_status" : "closed", "timeTrack_cameraName" : "M0006", "timeTrackCreationDate" : ISODate("2022-06-29T21:32:07.869Z"), "__v" : 0, "timeTrack_dateOfEnd" : ISODate("2022-06-29T21:37:40.398Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("62bd3757b186630330c70ea2"), "timeTrack_dateOfStart" : ISODate("2022-06-30T05:40:39.260Z"), "timeTrack_uniqueID" : "1656567639260", "timeTrack_profile_uniqueID" : "306", "timeTrack_status" : "closed", "timeTrack_cameraName" : "M0003", "timeTrackCreationDate" : ISODate("2022-06-30T05:40:39.265Z"), "__v" : 0, "timeTrack_dateOfEnd" : ISODate("2022-06-30T06:01:45.319Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("62c3981c0f769954f441986f"), "timeTrack_dateOfStart" : ISODate("2022-07-05T01:47:08.936Z"), "timeTrack_uniqueID" : "1656985628936", "timeTrack_profile_uniqueID" : "306", "timeTrack_status" : "closed", "timeTrack_cameraName" : "M0003", "timeTrackCreationDate" : ISODate("2022-07-05T01:47:08.940Z"), "__v" : 0, "timeTrack_dateOfEnd" : ISODate("2022-07-05T01:52:46.584Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("62c3bd1b33be5748ecc90832"), "timeTrack_dateOfStart" : ISODate("2022-07-05T04:24:59.192Z"), "timeTrack_uniqueID" : "1656995099192", "timeTrack_profile_uniqueID" : "71", "timeTrack_status" : "closed", "timeTrack_cameraName" : "M0001", "timeTrackCreationDate" : ISODate("2022-07-05T04:24:59.195Z"), "__v" : 0, "timeTrack_dateOfEnd" : ISODate("2022-07-05T04:27:11.343Z"), "timeTrack_playTimeTotal" : "2" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("62c3be0b3145a25b4037a978"), "timeTrack_dateOfStart" : ISODate("2022-07-05T04:28:59.462Z"), "timeTrack_uniqueID" : "1656995339462", "timeTrack_profile_uniqueID" : "71", "timeTrack_status" : "closed", "timeTrack_cameraName" : "M0001", "timeTrackCreationDate" : ISODate("2022-07-05T04:28:59.467Z"), "__v" : 0, "timeTrack_dateOfEnd" : ISODate("2022-07-05T04:31:17.220Z"), "timeTrack_playTimeTotal" : "2" }
```

Comment: Instead, you can write an Aggregation Query and avoid the JS code to get your result. The query will have a `$group` stage, which groups by `timeTrack_profile_uniqueID` and sums (use `$sum` operator) to add the difference between tow date fields (use `$subtract` operator). See the example in the documentation for guidance: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#examples

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this using `Object.values` and `Array.reduce`

```js
const transform = (data) => Object.values(data.reduce((res, {timeTrack_profile_uniqueID, timeTrack_dateOfStart, timeTrack_dateOfEnd}) => {
 const track_profileID = timeTrack_profile_uniqueID
 const duration = new Date(timeTrack_dateOfEnd).getTime() - new Date(timeTrack_dateOfStart).getTime() 
  const existing = res[track_profileID] || {track_profileID, track_totalTime: 0}
  return {
    ...res,
    [track_profileID]: {...existing, track_totalTime: existing.track_totalTime + duration}
  }
}, {})).map(t => ({...t, track_totalTime: Math.round(t.track_totalTime / 60000)}))


const data = [{ "_id" : "62bbeb23175d673b68c2bf27", "timeTrack_dateOfStart" : "2022-06-29T06:03:15.683Z", "timeTrack_uniqueID" : "1656482595683", "timeTrack_profile_uniqueID" : "306", "timeTrack_status" : "closed", "timeTrack_cameraName" : "M0003", "timeTrackCreationDate" : "2022-06-29T06:03:15.684Z", "__v" : 0, "timeTrack_dateOfEnd" : "2022-06-29T06:05:11.118Z" },
{ "_id" : "62bbebc7175d673b68c2bf29", "timeTrack_dateOfStart" : "2022-06-29T06:05:59.640Z", "timeTrack_uniqueID" : "1656482759640", "timeTrack_profile_uniqueID" : "306", "timeTrack_status" : "closed", "timeTrack_cameraName" : "M0003", "timeTrackCreationDate" : "2022-06-29T06:05:59.640Z", "__v" : 0, "timeTrack_dateOfEnd" : "2022-06-29T06:08:06.230Z" },
{ "_id" : "62bbf265859b02800cf2edfe", "timeTrack_dateOfStart" : "2022-06-29T06:34:13.424Z", "timeTrack_uniqueID" : "1656484453424", "timeTrack_profile_uniqueID" : "71", "timeTrack_status" : "closed", "timeTrack_cameraName" : "M0002", "timeTrackCreationDate" : "2022-06-29T06:34:13.425Z", "__v" : 0, "timeTrack_dateOfEnd" : "2022-06-29T06:52:24.396Z" },
{ "_id" : "62bbf265859b02800cf2ee01", "timeTrack_dateOfStart" : "2022-06-29T06:34:13.482Z", "timeTrack_uniqueID" : "1656484453482", "timeTrack_profile_uniqueID" : "305", "timeTrack_status" : "closed", "timeTrack_cameraName" : "M0002", "timeTrackCreationDate" : "2022-06-29T06:34:13.483Z", "__v" : 0, "timeTrack_dateOfEnd" : "2022-06-29T06:49:04.146Z" },
{ "_id" : "62bbf26d859b02800cf2ee03", "timeTrack_dateOfStart" : "2022-06-29T06:34:21.798Z", "timeTrack_uniqueID" : "1656484461798", "timeTrack_profile_uniqueID" : "306", "timeTrack_status" : "closed", "timeTrack_cameraName" : "M0003", "timeTrackCreationDate" : "2022-06-29T06:34:21.799Z", "__v" : 0, "timeTrack_dateOfEnd" : "2022-06-29T06:42:34.340Z" },
{ "_id" : "62bbf6197768b884d4e33a82", "timeTrack_dateOfStart" : "2022-06-29T06:50:01.907Z", "timeTrack_uniqueID" : "1656485401907", "timeTrack_profile_uniqueID" : "306", "timeTrack_status" : "closed", "timeTrack_cameraName" : "M0003", "timeTrackCreationDate" : "2022-06-29T06:50:01.910Z", "__v" : 0, "timeTrack_dateOfEnd" : "2022-06-29T06:59:49.865Z" },
{ "_id" : "62bbf6f07768b884d4e33a83", "timeTrack_dateOfStart" : "2022-06-29T06:53:36.978Z", "timeTrack_uniqueID" : "1656485616978", "timeTrack_profile_uniqueID" : "71", "timeTrack_status" : "closed", "timeTrack_cameraName" : "M0001", "timeTrackCreationDate" : "2022-06-29T06:53:36.979Z", "__v" : 0, "timeTrack_dateOfEnd" : "2022-06-29T07:07:23.639Z" },
{ "_id" : "62bcc4d7453bcf3850df4eb5", "timeTrack_dateOfStart" : "2022-06-29T21:32:07.868Z", "timeTrack_uniqueID" : "1656538327868", "timeTrack_profile_uniqueID" : "304", "timeTrack_status" : "closed", "timeTrack_cameraName" : "M0006", "timeTrackCreationDate" : "2022-06-29T21:32:07.869Z", "__v" : 0, "timeTrack_dateOfEnd" : "2022-06-29T21:37:40.398Z" },
{ "_id" : "62bd3757b186630330c70ea2", "timeTrack_dateOfStart" : "2022-06-30T05:40:39.260Z", "timeTrack_uniqueID" : "1656567639260", "timeTrack_profile_uniqueID" : "306", "timeTrack_status" : "closed", "timeTrack_cameraName" : "M0003", "timeTrackCreationDate" : "2022-06-30T05:40:39.265Z", "__v" : 0, "timeTrack_dateOfEnd" : "2022-06-30T06:01:45.319Z" },
{ "_id" : "62c3981c0f769954f441986f", "timeTrack_dateOfStart" : "2022-07-05T01:47:08.936Z", "timeTrack_uniqueID" : "1656985628936", "timeTrack_profile_uniqueID" : "306", "timeTrack_status" : "closed", "timeTrack_cameraName" : "M0003", "timeTrackCreationDate" : "2022-07-05T01:47:08.940Z", "__v" : 0, "timeTrack_dateOfEnd" : "2022-07-05T01:52:46.584Z" },
{ "_id" : "62c3bd1b33be5748ecc90832", "timeTrack_dateOfStart" : "2022-07-05T04:24:59.192Z", "timeTrack_uniqueID" : "1656995099192", "timeTrack_profile_uniqueID" : "71", "timeTrack_status" : "closed", "timeTrack_cameraName" : "M0001", "timeTrackCreationDate" : "2022-07-05T04:24:59.195Z", "__v" : 0, "timeTrack_dateOfEnd" : "2022-07-05T04:27:11.343Z", "timeTrack_playTimeTotal" : "2" },
{ "_id" : "62c3be0b3145a25b4037a978", "timeTrack_dateOfStart" : "2022-07-05T04:28:59.462Z", "timeTrack_uniqueID" : "1656995339462", "timeTrack_profile_uniqueID" : "71", "timeTrack_status" : "closed", "timeTrack_cameraName" : "M0001", "timeTrackCreationDate" : "2022-07-05T04:28:59.467Z", "__v" : 0, "timeTrack_dateOfEnd" : "2022-07-05T04:31:17.220Z", "timeTrack_playTimeTotal" : "2" }]

console.log(transform(data))
```

Comment: @dunemanns if you like it please accept the answer